# Using knex to create graphql resolvers

Tags: database, postgresql, graphql

I am querying my database using graphQL. I am stuck on writing the graphQL resolvers to my database, using knexjs.

My problem is I want that a query or mutation to use only 1 database connection (correct me if this is wrong, but I really think this is true).

For instance, the call to the server

```
query {
    post {
        author
    }
}
```

should use 2 database calls for the `post` and `author` fields, done in a single connection to the database.

I think transactions are the way to go, and I implemented resolvers using transactions (here is a toy example):

```
const trxProvider = knex.transactionProvider();

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        post: async () => {
            const trx = await trxProvider();
            let res = await trx('posts')

            return res
        },

        author: async () => {
            const trx = await trxProvider();
            let res = await trx('authors')
            return res
        }
    }
}
```

1. How do I properly resolve this transaction? For instance, how would I call `trx.commit()` when a query/mutation has completed so the connection does not idle?
2. Are transactions the correct approach / What knex functionality should I use so that a single database connection is used for a query +mutation?

Answering any of these questions is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection pooling is the preferred approach. Transactions are best used to wrap multiple database *writes* so that all the writes can be committed or rolled back together. This avoids inconsistent writes. I've found no advantage to using transactions for *reads*.

I've published a [tutorial](https://michelfloyd.hashnode.dev/graphql-for-sql-developers-part-1) that covers a lot of what you need to do with knex and GraphQL. Hopefully you'll find it helpful.

Comment: I keep getting 'too many connections' errors with my postgres database. Do I have to resolve / commit the connection somehow?

Comment: [How to configure the knex connection pool](https://knexjs.org/guide/#pool)

Comment: Should I need to do any configuration for pooling, or should everything be handled correctly automatically (I set minpooling to 0, maxpooling to 5)

Comment: should be sufficient, no extra config needed.